# How to modify Laravel 5 AuthController postRegister() function with "Remember me"

Tags: php

The default `postRegister()` function in AuthController performs the user authentication if the user registration has been successful. However, this login dose not include the Remember me. How to override the function to perform Remember me login after the registration?

I modified the `postRegister()` function as following.

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->registrar->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    $this->registrar->create($request->all());

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
        ->withErrors(['activated' => 'Activation link has been sent to your email address.']);
}
```